# PowerPoint Add-in Add a textbox to a selected slide

Tags: vba, textbox, powerpoint, add-in

I'm trying to make a button that when clicked, will add two text boxes to the selected slide in a specified place with specified formatting (font, size, color, justified). I've been trying to reverse engineer anything applicable, but just end up breaking things. This set of code will allow me to make a rectangle (not a textbox which is preferred) size it and place it (just 1 not 2) with sample text.. For the life of me I cant figure out how to make it create a textbox on the selected slide or active window.. what am I doing wrong? Heres the code I found..

```
Sub AddTextBox()

Set myDocument = ActivePresentation.Slides(1)

With myDocument.Shapes _
        .AddTextBox(msoShapeRectangle, 180, 175, 350, 140).TextFrame
    .TextRange.Text = "Ctrl+A(Select all), Ctrl+V(Paste)"
    .MarginTop = 10
    
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

To refer to the slide that's currently being displayed, you can use the Slide Property of the View object...

```
Dim mySlide As Slide
Set mySlide = ActiveWindow.View.Slide
```

For creating a textbox, here's the proper syntax as per the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.shapes.addtextbox?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbapp10.chm543014);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)...

> Syntax
>
> expression. AddTextbox( *Orientation*, *Left*, *Top*, *Width*,
> *Height* )
>
> expression A variable that represents a Shapes object.

So, in your case, it would be something like this...

```
Dim myTextbox As Shape
Set myTextbox = mySlide.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 180, 175, 350, 140)
```

Change the text orientation as desired.